# asciidoc: FAILED: configuration file asciidoc.conf missing

Tags: git, makefile, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am trying to build git as a user without root.

```
make configure
./configure --prefix=/home/tools/bin/git/$ver
make all doc
```

and I get this error:

```
make[2]: `GIT-VERSION-FILE' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/tools/bin/git/src/git-2.24.1'
    * new asciidoc flags
    ASCIIDOC git-archive.html
asciidoc: FAILED: configuration file asciidoc.conf missing
make[1]: *** [git-archive.html] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tools/bin/git/src/git-2.24.1/Documentation'
make: *** [doc] Error 2
```

I have asciidoc, xmlto, makeinfo, docbook2X installed.  I have tried adding absolute paths to all the occurrences of asciidoc.conf I could find but no difference.  General search only turns up one discussion on a google group 4 years ago but the OP didn't bother to share the fix.  Any suggestions?

It seems asciidoctor is another option, but I don't know how to enable it.

Comment: Was this a Git-for-Windows build (via the sdk), Cygwin or a Linux distro?  I'm seeing the same issue in the GfW sdk when building the Git documentation.

Comment: CentOS7 for me.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your AsciiDoc version is misconfigured and can't find its own configuration file.  You'd need to tell it when building it where it should find that file at runtime, or use your distro's packages.

You can also use Asciidoctor to build instead.  There isn't a `configure` option for it, but you can invoke make like `USE_ASCIIDOCTOR=1 make all doc` to set the flag.  Note that you'll need at least Git 2.24 to have everything working with Asciidoctor 2, which you appear to have.

Comment: Thank you, but asciidoctor doesn't work for me, either.


`/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in to_specs: Could not find 'asciidoctor' (>= 0) among 5 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)`

but I have ruby and asciidoctor installed.

Comment: It sounds like you have a problem with finding gems.  I'm not sure why, but it works correctly for me from a Debian buster container.  You could try not building the documentation if you can't get anything to work.

Comment: I am able to build without doc so I am doing that for now.  At least it is working.  

Regarding asciidoc, I did use the distro package.  Now because I do not have sudo I had to install it elsewhere, but it is in the path.  However, if asciidoc is looking for something in a system area then that might be a problem.  I don't know what other flags to try.

Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: This `USE_ASCIIDOCTOR=1 make all doc` worked for me (again). Too much tripping over my own shoe laces at the moment ;-)